# Lenovo Thinkpad e531 camera issue

Tags: thinkpad, webcam, camera

When I use the Windows 10 camera app, the camera works normally, but when I open it as a Capture device in VLC player it starts light then app kills.

I tried it in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

Also, the same thing in VLC works on my brother's HP laptop.

I'm trying to follow this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Z5c28rd5Wk

Comment: I'm unclear to what  " it starts light then app kills."  means

Comment: Camera start lights then vlc app killed